# C convertir string de fecha en BCD

Tags: c, string

Necesito convertir un string que contiene una fecha a formato BCD.

ejemplo de lo que necesito obtener:
19941012  -> 0x1994 0x10 0x12

Lo que hago es "trocear" el string y llamar a la función con los caracteres que quiero convertir. Primero los cuatro caracteres del año, después dos para el mes y por último dos para el día.

He probado algunos ejemplos como el que detallo pero no obtengo resultados.

```
 char DecimalToBcd(char cadena)
 {
  return (char) ((cadena / 10)*16)+(cadena % 10);
 }
```

Saludos

Comment: Piensa que el char '0' no tiene el valor numérico 0. char usa la codificación ASCII, así que el caracter impreso 0 tiene el valor 48, el 1 el 49... Además, ¿porqué el módulo y la división por 10? ¿No debería "cadena" ser ya un char entre '0' y '9'?

Answer (score 0):

Finalmente he dado con ello

En el foro en ingles el compañero Simon Peverett publica una función muy sencilla que me ha funcionado perfectamente.

Con el permiso de Simon Peverett os muestro la funcíon

```
uint32_t dec2bcd_r(uint16_t dec)
{
   return (dec) ? 
   ((dec2bcd_r( 
   dec / 10 ) << 
   4) + (dec % 
   10)) : 0;
 }
```